# How to store data in the flash memory of a Arduino Uno (ATmega328p)

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega

I have a project with a Arduino Uno where I need to store a char** that is too big for EPROM.

I am currently trying to do it with serial but I could also use a AVRISP programmer if needed (Not preferable)

So far I have looked into the avr/boot.h API but I am not really sure how to use it properly or if it is even the correct way to do it.

Comment: Its not clear for me if you want to store static data or dynamic data, since you mention potentially doing it by AVRISP programmer. Is the data known at compile time?

Comment: @Rev1.0 it is not known at compile time, I want to make a program that lets the end user load in settings to customise the device, so no not at compile time.

Comment: OK. The normal way to go would probably be to use some external EEPROM. Another way could be similar to receiving an Firmware update. Boot the device on request -> receive your data from boot loader code -> write data to specific address near the end of flash address space -> continue to main program which knows where to look for the data.

Comment: Writing continuosly the MCU FLASH is not a good idea, It's not guaranted that you may write it an indefinite number of times! It's probably better to use an external memory more performant of the MCU Flash that are declared for 10000 write/erase cycles.

Comment: @Rev1.0 "Boot the device on request -> receive your data from boot loader code -> write data to specific address near the end of flash address space -> continue to main program which knows where to look for the data." would be perfect but I have no clue how.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini, I know the write/erase cycles, this is for an embedded device and the user may only need to do this 1 time in its lifetime at most 10-15 so there should be no issues.

Comment: Regarding your comment: You can only write to the flash from the boot loader section. So you have to receive your config data from the boot loader code. You could write a PC tool which communicates with the uC via UART/RS232. While running the uC main program it listens for a command from the PC to restart itself. When it does receive that command, it start into the bootloader, waiting for further instructions from PC tool (timeout). The tool can then initiate transferring the config data to the uC which is written to a specific flash address. Afterwards the main code can access that data.

Comment: (not enough chars...) It is not trivial but totally doable. Look into how a boot loader works to update the main application, its the mechanism you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ATmega328P datasheet, "Boot Loader Support" section, "Application and Boot Loader Flash Sections" subsection, "Application Section" subsubsection:

> ... the SPM instruction is disabled when executed from the Application section.

Therefore there is no way to write to flash from the running program. Use an external memory device if you need to store more data than fits on-board.

Answer (score 5):

The arduino (specifically atmel 328 versions) only allow you to write to flash memory when the bootloader allows it.

The standard bootloader allows you to write to flash when a new program is being installed, but does not allow runtime programs to write to flash.

Solution:  Install a bootloader that does allow you to run functions that enable you to write to flash.

Here is a bootloader (featured on hackaday) for an arduino that allows you to write to flash memory during runtime  http://majek.mamy.to/en/writing-to-internal-flash-on-arduino/

Here is the hackaday post on the subject
https://hackaday.com/2015/07/03/arduinos-and-other-avrs-write-to-own-flash/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that's correct.  The 328p does have the ability to control what some instructions about where they are allowed to access. I didn't see anywhere that this wasn't possible and in some configurations it (328p) can write flash under it's own control.

I searched the data sheet for 'SPM instruction is disabled' and hit only on the ATmega 48a/48pa. Having confused myself many times with that datasheet reading about the wrong controller.  This didn't ring a bell.

Copied directly from the datasheet (660 pages):

"The ATmega 48A/48PA has no separate Boot Loader section, and the SPM instruction is enabled for the whole Flash if the SELFPRGEN fuse is programmed (“0”). Otherwise the SPM instruction is disabled."

The 328p has 'Lock Bit Byte' sets all of these controls, generally speaking.
These also control what access they have.

I would think you'd want to put it into eeprom (which IS different)...

Jack